# undefindex index, mysqli_query, no result spit back

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm following a tutorial to build a calendar. Originally, it was build with mysql, I rewrote it a little to mysqli to follow php recommendations.

I'm stuck at the very final step, I'm trying to get the description for an event/day out of a database. I'm getting no/emtpy results.

My table for the calendar looks like this: [id] [evdate] [description]

Here's my code, I get a notice undefinded index on line 13 - Thanks a lot for help

```
$deets = $_POST['deets'];
$deets = preg_replace('#[^0-9/]#i', '', $deets);

include_once('inc/connection.inc.php');
$events = '';
$sql = "SELECT id FROM events WHERE evdate = '$deets'";
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows ($query);
if($num_rows > 0){
    $events .= '<div id="eventControl"><button onmousedown="overlay()">Close</button><br><strong>'. $deets .'</strong></div>'; // Add a close Button
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $desc = $row['description']; // Notice undefindex Index :(
    $events .= '<div id="eventsbody">'. $desc .'</div>';
}
}
echo $events;
```

Comment: You're only selecting `id`, so the `$row` doesn't contain a `description`.

Comment: There's also no point in using mysqli, if you don't utilize parameterized queries.

Comment: @mario While it's a good idea to use parametrized queries, that's not the only reason to use mysqli.

Answer (score 1):

You're only selecting `id` but trying to retrieve `description`.  Update your query as:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, description FROM events WHERE evdate = '$deets'";
```

Comment: You guys are insanely fast and good - first of all - I can't believe it was that simple, but logic. Secondly, hmm I see, ok, I'll have to get over prepared statements again. Thanks a lot for all answers, thumbs up!